# Print this Alphabetical Pattern using 2 loops

Tags: java, loops

I need to print this pattern in java using only 2 loops one for the row and the second for the column.

```
A B C D E 
 B C D E 
  C D E 
   D E 
    E  
   D E 
  C D E 
 B C D E 
A B C D E
```

**What I've tried**

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 5;
        char c = 'A';
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){
            int k=1;
            for(int j=1; j<=(n*2)-1; j++){
                if(j>=i && j<=((n*2)-i) && k!=0){
                    System.out.print(c);
                    k=0;
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    k=1;
                    c++;
                }
            }
            c = 'A';
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
}
```

Output: This logic is printing half of the pattern correctly as I'm unable to understand how to built for the second half.

Comment: Just keep trying; if you were able to print the first half, you'll be able to print the second half.

Comment: @akuzminykh but how can I use the same loops for printing the reverse pattern

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same logic as you used to print the top half, with the outer for-loop reversed, i.e., change:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
```

to:

```
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
```

**Full code:**

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    printHourGlass(5);
  }

  public static void printHourGlass(int n) {
    char c = 'A';
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      int k = 1;
      for (int j = 1; j <= (n * 2) - 1; j++) {
        if (j >= i && j <= ((n * 2) - i) && k != 0) {
          System.out.print(c);
          k = 0;
        } else {
          System.out.print(" ");
          k = 1;
          c++;
        }
      }
      c = 'A';
      System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
      int k = 1;
      for (int j = 1; j <= (n * 2) - 1; j++) {
        if (j >= i && j <= ((n * 2) - i) && k != 0) {
          System.out.print(c);
          k = 0;
        } else {
          System.out.print(" ");
          k = 1;
          c++;
        }
      }
      c = 'A';
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
A B C D E
 B C D E 
  C D E  
   D E   
    E    
   D E   
  C D E  
 B C D E 
A B C D E
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work for any terminating letter from 'B' to 'Z', define some values.

```
String indent = "                                     ";
char endLetter = 'E';
int end = endLetter - 'A';
```

The first part is easy and fairly straight forward.

- use substring with `indent` to control indenting.
- then print the characters incrementing the inner and outer loop until done.

```
for (int k = 0; k <= end; k++) {
    System.out.print(indent.substring(0,k));
    for (char c = (char)('A' + k); c <= endLetter; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
A B C D E 
 B C D E 
  C D E 
   D E 
    E
```

The trick is to reverse the process, continuing the outer loop.

- the outer loop now goes from `0 to end*2+1`
- and `k` is replaced by `s`

  - using `int s = k <= end ? k : end*2 - k;`
  - s becomes `0 1 2 3 4 ... n ... n-1  n-2 ... 4 3 2 1 0`

```
for (int k = 0; k < end*2+1; k++) {
    int s = k <= end ? k : end*2 - k;
    System.out.print(indent.substring(0,s));
    for (char c = (char) ('A' + s); c <= endLetter; c++) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints

```
A B C D E 
 B C D E 
  C D E 
   D E 
    E 
   D E 
  C D E 
 B C D E 
A B C D E
```

Note that in Java 11 `String.repeat` was added so that could also be used to indent the appropriate lines.  So the printing of the indent could be `System.out.print(" ".repeat(s));`

Note: ASCII letters are adjacent from a-z with upper and lower case in different positions of the ASCII chart.  Since they are treated as ints in the `char` type they can be mathematically altered to be other characters.  So `'A'+1` is a `'B'` and so forth. That is why the inner loops above work as they do.